# How to prevent XSS attack in wordpress theme?

Tags: theme-development, customization, themes

I am creating a WordPress theme. What should i do, to prevent XSS attack in WordPress theme?
i did not found much about it for WordPress Themes.

Answer (score 0):

XSS generally would only occur through AJAX or form handling. Verify a referrer header is actually from your FQDN and/or require a captcha, providing pseudorandom input validation.

Comment: nice to see your answer but i need a better solution if i do not use captcha? i have tried this [XSS attack](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/cross-site-scripting-in-wordpress-practical-tips-for-securing-your-site--wp-30517) on twenty-thirteen comments and it infected.